# Let's have the credits roll on this [role-playing-game]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

I'm not sure why a [role-playing-game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/role-playing-game) is needed when there's already a [game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) tag. Personally, I think we should just burninate it and add the [game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) tag to all the questions tagged with it that don't already have the [game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) tag. I just don't think that we need specific tags for genres of games, when a [game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) tag suffices.

Comment: It is worth noting that there are tons of tags for specific games or game types. What make RPG special? Or should they all be burned?

Comment: I disagree on the burnination, will write an answer shortly.

Comment: @nhgrif I was not aware of other tags. Could you give a few examples, to be specific?

Comment: Related: [Should adventure-game and role-playing-game be synonymized?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5041/should-adventure-game-and-role-playing-game-be-synonymized) and [When to create own tag for games](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2503/game-tag-when-to-create-own-tag-for-games)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## No, do not burninate

We **do** need specific tags for games. See [Game tag - When to create own tag for games?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2503/game-tag-when-to-create-own-tag-for-games)

Some genres of games, are popular enough that they do deserve their own tag.

For example, I am a huge fan of [minesweeper](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minesweeper), having asked several questions about it and having spent countless hours analyzing the game, I am definitely interested in that tag.

Now, what does [minesweeper](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minesweeper) and [role-playing-game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/role-playing-game) share with each other? Honestly, not that much. The [game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) tag is a bit too unspecific. The only 'problem' with the game tags is to have tags that are specific enough, but still un-specific enough to contain a bunch of questions. I find [role-playing-game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/role-playing-game) to be a very good balance here.

If you think about the world outside Code Review (yes, there is one, or so I've heard at least), Role Playing Games (or RPGs) is a quite specific genre. It definitely deserves its own tag.